# Java Social Networking, friends' activity status awareness efficient method

Tags: java, mysql, performance, networking

Assume you having a social networking website where you can have friends and also view their up to date activities.  The question is, what is the most efficient way (avoiding performance problem) to be informed of their activities right away such as changing profile when they're online and you're online as well at the same time?

I have two different ways working out this but I am not precisely sure which one will be the most efficient method from DB point of view as well as Java memory point of view.  The followings are my methods, and please let me know if you have any better way:
1-  Using java HTTP Session Listener to get session of each single user and traverse through for updates.
2-  Checking database for new updates after every few seconds and then updating the map.

Comment: So, you're asking whether you should use the Facebook real-time updates, or the Graph API.

Comment: Kind of Facebook real time update but the application I am talking about is nothing to do with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

First: you will only know after you have done measurements.

Having said this, there is always a space-time-tradeoff. Meaning that if you store a lot of stuff in memory, it will be fast, but you have a large memory footprint. If you go via DB, you will have a small (java) footprint, but will be a lot slower.

So you need to decide what to do. Memory is cheap, so putting stuff in a memory cache will work nicely. But on the other hand, do you really need sub-second updates? Or can an update of a profile be 20sec old, before it is detected?

There is a great episode of the SE-Radio podcast on NoSQL databases that talks a lot about those decisions to make: http://www.se-radio.net/2010/05/episode-162-project-voldemort-with-jay-kreps/ (I hope it is this one)

This episode about memory-grids is also quite good: http://www.se-radio.net/2010/11/episode-169-memory-grid-architecture-with-nati-shalom/

Comment: Yes that is right java memory is much faster than DB. In my scenario there are two different updates, one connects to DB after each few seconds to reload Java map and the second one is retrieving data from various sessions. What really worries me is that keep expanding java memory it might be overused and out of memory exception might occur particularly with social networking sites.  I really couldn't find any article about facebook or twitter server's clustering that tells how much memory is assigned on X server to X user.

Comment: The memory cache you are using needs an eviction policy that throws out old entries. This can happen after a certain age has reached or after a certain count. You may again just measure: measure the app size with 0, 1000, 2000, 10000 users and then you'll see how memory usage grows and can anticipate the number of users per node. You will need some load testing anyway, so you can set it up early and measure with its help.

Comment: Thanks Heiko this is what I was after but I was lazy to do some further implementation. Thanks once again for your replies.

Comment: I am kind of new to this site, I tried but I guess one has to have at least 15 reputations to vote.  No worries will do this once I gained that many reputations.